# PHP Amazon S3 Upload Speed

Tags: php, upload, amazon-s3

I am using a [PHP Amazon S3 Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/) (which seems to be highly recommended and widely used) and have found that the speed of a file upload is extremely slow compared to if I use the command line [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) utility.

For example, the same 20mb file took 2.8 seconds via s3cmd and around 54 seconds via php:

Command Line:

```
s3cmd put archive.tar.gz s3://bucket
```

Output: *File 'archive.tar.gz' stored as s3://bucket/archive.tar.gz (23320623 bytes in 2.8 seconds, 8.07 MB/s) [1 of 1]*

PHP:

```
$time = time();

$s3 = new S3('ACCESS KEY','SECRET KEY');
$s3->putObjectFile('archive.tar.gz','bucket','archive.tar.gz');

echo 'Done in '.(time()-$time).' seconds';
```

Output: *Done in 54 seconds*

Is this just something I have to accept if using PHP to upload to S3? Or is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing? I just can't see why there would be such a huge discrepancy in the upload speed and as I need to do this with much bigger files in the future, such slowness is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable SSL!

```
$s3 = new S3('ACCESS KEY','SECRET KEY', false);
```

And now it is speeeeeeding along.

Comment: This is a bad solution. This means you're sending your secret key (a.k.a. password) over the open internet. Furthermore, it's very unlikely SSL is causing a 2.8 -> 54 second slowdown -- SSL perhaps takes a couple extra seconds to bootstrap, but doesn't significantly affect the upload speed of the file.

Comment: @asuth No, as long as SSL is the problem, this is a fine solution. You're not sending the secret key over the open internet. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html - the secret is hashed with select elements of the request you are making. As for whether it is SSL causing the slowdown, at the time of the question it was the only factor which was making such a major difference - I cannot dispute that this may point at a bigger issue, though.